# Building a distributed bittorrent-SQL database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, bittorrent, bittorrent-sync

I have an idea for a **distributed SQL database** using the bittorrent protocol for pulling and writing its data.

For the sake of argument, lets say this is a messaging application, where thousands of users run a program that contains a messaging window, and an input box for them to write messages.

Each message written does a INSERT to their own sqlite DB.

### How it could be done

- Download a .torrent file that essentially contains the schema/DDL for creating the DB, and create it on the local machines.
- Anytime a 'write' action is done(like a user wants to send a message), that INSERT line(which is kinda like a delta) does two things:

  - Writes to their own internal DB
  - Creates a .torrent file out of that line, named something like, messaging-[my-ip]-[UTC_timestamp].torrent, and posts it to a tracker
- Everyone running the app is continually scanning the tracker for files of this certain name(and possibly after a certain date), downloads the .torrent and hosts it, and runs the INSERT commands on their local DB.

What you'd then have is a ton of delta-files, all P2P hosted for redundancy, updating local .sqlite DBs on a lot of machines.

### Some issues I'm having

- How do I scrape for torrents of a certain file-name? I've read through the http bittorrent tracker spec, but you seem to only be able to query files based on their specific info name. Is there no way to query for a group of files, or based on file name?
- How do I download a .torrent file from a tracker? Will I need to host the files on a centralized server, or can I use the tracker to download the files in some way? And if I have to host the .torrent files myself...

  - Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of a decentralized DB, since if my website goes down, the application would stop getting updates?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I googled this thought as well and now I'm here. Bit torrent may not work well, so I think we should be using something custom, yet similar in spirit. Maybe mysql replication is a good start. Also maybe block chain could work.

Comment: possible solutions: [GitTorrent](https://github.com/cjb/GitTorrent), [dolt](https://github.com/dolthub/dolt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bittorrent is designed for distribution of immutable and somewhat large data sets and doesn't really know any operations that span multiple torrents.
Databases are mostly about mutating relatively small chunks of data and performing operations over diverse subsets of those.

You will have little joy trying to shoehorn database semantics into bittorent.

At best you can use it for distributing snapshots of a database.
With a little tinkering bittorrent can be fairly good at recycling data from previous torrents if the new content only adds/removes files (again, of significant size) without modifying old ones.

Anything beyond that would require some significant modifications to the protocol, it wouldn't really be vanilla bittorrent anymore.

Comment: > and doesn't really know any operations that span multiple torrents.

What about torrent rss feeds?

Comment: I guess you could count that. It's an optional part though, not essential for basic bittorrent functionality.

Comment: Isn't some of what I'm proposing above feasible? Just because bittorrent was built to sync large files, doesn't mean that this couldn't be done with a lot of small delta files.

Comment: some of it, maybe. but you might want to re-state your problem in filesystem terms instead of database terms. building any database logic on top of that would be a separate concern to bittorrent itself

Comment: I think this is an interesting question.  Progress has been made on allowing mutable torrents after this question has been asked.  More info is here: https://torrentfreak.com/mutable-torrents-proposal-makes-bittorrent-resilient-160813/

Comment: @Strat-O [BEP46](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0046.html) (would have been better to link that directly) is not really sufficient to get a distributed SQL database going. First of all, the update interval of BEP46 is fairly low, which may not be suitable for databases. Secondly OP wants to allow more than 1 writer, but 46 only is single-writer, multiple-reader.